# Web Components: Defining a function in class, access inline

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I am converting a website from Angular to Web components/polymer. What I need is to call a function called `lookupUser()` when a form is submitted. However I'm not sure how to define the function properly.

---

(just the relevant) **HTML**

`<form name="userLookupForm" class="search" onsubmit="lookupUser();">`

---

**Javascript**

```
(function(customElements) {
class DashboardSearch extends PolymerMixins.LightDomMixin(Polymer.Element) {
    static get is() {
        return 'dashboard-search';
    }

    static get config() {
        return {
                properties: {
                    user: {
                        type: Object
                    },
                },
            };
        }

        lookupUser() {
            if (scope.userlookup) {
                $state.go('users', {
                    query: scope.userlookup
                });
            }
        };

    }
    customElements.define(DashboardSearch.is, DashboardSearch);
})(window.customElements);
```

Ignoring the angular I have yet to remove from the function, how would I properly define this function so it can be called from `onsubmit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Polymer templates, event listeners can be added declaratively using the `on-*` annotation syntax. Instead of `onsubmit="lookupUser();"` you need to use `on-submit="lookupUser"`. Note that the value is just the name of the method; no parentheses or data-binding brackets (`on-submit="[[lookupUser]]"` is a very common mistake).

```html
<form name="userLookupForm" class="search" on-submit="lookupUser">
```

Then, in your class, you want to define a `lookupUser` method. Just like event listeners added with `addEventListener`, it will receive a single argument, the Event object.

```js
class DashboardSearch extends PolymerMixins.LightDomMixin(Polymer.Element) {
  static get is() {
    return 'dashboard-search';
  }
  static get config() {
    // ...
  }

  lookupUser(event) {
    console.log(event.target); // => logs <form> element
  }
}
```

This is covered in the [Handle and fire events](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events) section of the official docs.